# AWS DMS CDC using Oracle as source not working properly

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, database-migration, cdc

I'm working on migrating a lot of tables hosted on Oracle to Aurora MySQL using AWS Database Migration Service (Full Load + CDC). However, I noticed some updates/delete/inserts weren't captured when comparing the target with the source (The redo logs are read by LogMinner). Also, I checked the Cloudwatch metrics of the instance and the source delay is over 17 hours. Adding information, the instance is a DMS.C5.xLarge. Has anyone addressed this issue before?

Comment: The Oracle version is 10g.